# nivo slider image Link and IE not working

Tags: image, internet-explorer, hyperlink, slider, nivo-slider

hi i have been trying for hours to get the image links inside the slider to work in IE 9 they work fine in Chrome can any one help

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved it with specifying the z-index.  Make sure to specify the anchor tag's class also ( a.nivo-imageLink ) or else you will mess up navigation anchors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, This is well-known and documented. I found your question with the same problem, this fixed it for me:

```
.nivoSlider a {
  border:0;
  display:block;
  background-color: #fff;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-opacity:0;
  -moz-opacity:0;
  -khtml-opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved it with specifying the z-index.  Make sure to specify the anchor tag's class also ( a.nivo-imageLink ) or else you will mess up navigation anchors.